# Is there a way to overwrite False to True?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which currently looks like this.

Original Table

| Test Subject | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | True | False | False |
| Subject2 | True | False | False |
| Subject3 | True | False | False |
| Subject2 | False | False | False |
| Subject2 | False | True | True |
| Subject3 | False | False | True |

Is there any possible way for me to group the test subjects and overwrite previous values within their column to make it look like the following without doing it manually?

Desired Table

| Test Subject | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | True | False | False |
| Subject2 | True | True | True |
| Subject3 | True | False | True |

Attached code to make the original dataframe from scratch

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Test Subject': ["Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject3", "Subject2", "Subject2", "Subject3"], 'Test1': [True, True, True, False, False, False], 'Test2': [False, False, False, True, False, False], 'Test3': [False, False, False, False, True, True]})
```

EDIT: The table formatting seems to be broken for some reason so I've posted photos below of the tables

Original Table
[Original Table created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4psX.png)

Desired Table
[Desired Table from question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsu5.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df.groupby('Test Subject', as_index=False).any()

  Test Subject  Test1  Test2  Test3
0     Subject1   True  False  False
1     Subject2   True   True   True
2     Subject3   True  False   True
```

If any value in the group is True, it returns True

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) :

```
out = df.groupby('Test Subject', as_index=False).agg('sum').replace({1:True, 0:False})
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]